# Android long click on tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, onlongclicklistener

I have a TabHost with some tabs, and after doing a long press on a tab, I want to get the position or the tag of the tab which was long pressed, and not the current tab that is showed.
Below there is some code in which I create the long press listener for the TabHost:

```
myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any solution? Is correct to apply the listener at TabHost in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem adding to the view of the tab a tag information , and then I attached at the view a listener that gets and prints this tag:

```
View tabView= mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
// set the tag information at the view of the tab (the tag contains the position number of the tab)
tabView.setTag( Integer.valueOf(i));
tabView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // I print the number position of the tab
                Log.d("tab number", ((Integer)view.getTag()).toString() );
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier of the tab that was long-clicked resides in the `View v` parameter of the `onLongClick` function. Call `v.getId()` and the rest are details

Comment: v.getId() returns me always -1

Answer (score 0):

```
val tabCount = binding.tabLayout.tabCount
for (index in 0 until tabCount) {
   binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(index)?.apply {
   view.isLongClickable = false
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         view.tooltipText = ""
      }
   }
}
```