# Create contextMenu on TabLayout

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, android-tablayout, android-contextmenu

Is it possible to show a `ContextMenu` when the user long pressed on a Tab.

**Here's my tabs**

[image]

**XML that creates the TabLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**What've tried.**

```
TabLayout#tlCategories.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
Activity#registerForContextMenu(tlCategories);
```

but that's not worked :(,

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17482956/4370279) answer, but is it possible to show the ContextMenu through the way we usually do with the `registerForContextMenu` ?

Comment: Are you looking for [ActionMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html)?

Comment: No sufian, I need ContextMenu